# Proving $E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X\geq i)$ for a R.V which receives non-negative values

Tags: probability-theory, summation, expectation

I'm refreshing my knowledge in probability and I cam across the following:

> Let $X$ be a discrete R.V that takes only non-negative values, then
>   $E[X]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(X\geq i)$

I have a small problem understating the proof given:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(X\geq i)
$$

$$
=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}P(X=j)
$$

$$
\overset{=}{\text{?}}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{j}P(X=j)
$$

$$
=\sum_{j=i}^{\infty}jP(X=j)=E[X]
$$

I don't understand the second equality - how did the second sum became
from $i=1$ to $i=j$ and the order of the inner and outer sums were
switched ?

Comment: You first have $1\leq i\leq j \leq \infty$. This clearly says that $1\leq i \leq j$, and "then" $1 \leq j \leq \infty$. Do you see the point?

Comment: @Math-fun - I do, its much simpler viewing it this way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

[image]

The sum
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=i}^\infty\Pr(X=j)
$$
adds the probabilities at the ordinates of the dots with the dots listed by **columns proceeding left to right**. The sum
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{i=1}^j\Pr(X=j)
$$
computes the same sum with the dots listed by **rows proceeding from bottom to top**. Of course, in each row, all the dots have the same ordinates and that's why you get the simplification on the very next step in the proof.